# Ruby Group Parts of An Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I start out with a following simple array, as such:

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

I want the below.  How do I get this?

```
a = ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```

Comment: What should happen if there are not an even number of elements in the array? Is a single letter returned, or is it dropped?

Answer (score 7):

```
a = a.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
```

`each_slice(2)` will produce an iterator that will yield pairs `["a", "b"]`, `["c", "d"]` and `["e", "f"]`. Then, for each of those pairs, `join` will stick them together, and `map` will collect them into an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

a.join.scan /../
  #=> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
```